# After adding code in this app, the app does not working

Tags: java, android

[error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq7gl.png)

After adding this code, the app does not working. What is the problem?
If remove this code, the app works normally.

```
int i, num=0, num2=0;
    for(i=0; i<=23; i++) {
        if(result[i] == 1) {
            num++;
        }
    }
    int[] Time = new int[num-1];
    for(i=0; i<=23; i++) {
        if(result[i] == 1) {
            Time[num2]=i;
            num2++;
        }
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Arrays.toString(Time), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

full code is this

```
package org.techtown.challenge09;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
SingerAdapter adapter;
EditText Name;
EditText Start;
EditText End;

Button button;


int[] result = new int[24];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Name = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Start = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    End = findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    adapter = new SingerAdapter();

    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String name = Name.getText().toString();
            String start = Start.getText().toString() + ":00";
            String end = End.getText().toString() + ":00";

            adapter.addItem(new SingerItem(name, start, end, R.drawable.human));


            int First = Integer.parseInt(Start.getText().toString());
            int Last = Integer.parseInt(End.getText().toString());
            for(int i=First; i<Last; i++) {
                result[i] = 1;
            }
        }

    });

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            SingerItem item = (SingerItem) adapter.getItem(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "선택 : " + item.getName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    int i, num=0, num2=0;
    for(i=0; i<=23; i++) {
        if(result[i] == 1) {
            num++;
        }
    }
    int[] Time = new int[num-1];
    for(i=0; i<=23; i++) {
        if(result[i] == 1) {
            Time[num2]=i;
            num2++;
        }
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Arrays.toString(Time), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public class SingerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<SingerItem> items = new ArrayList<SingerItem>();

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public void addItem(SingerItem item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        SingerItemView view = new SingerItemView(getApplicationContext());
        SingerItem item = items.get(position);
        view.setName(item.getName());
        view.setStart(item.getStart());
        view.setEnd(item.getEnd());
        view.setImage(item.getResId());

        return view;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Whats the stack trace?

Comment: maybe Toast is a blocking call and you do it in the ui thread (thus it blocks ui forever). try to wrap in a new thread just to see if that helps.

Comment: You should really follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names always start with lowercase. `Name`, `First`, `Last`, `Start` and `End` should be refactored accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is called after you tap on the Button:

```
int First = Integer.parseInt(Start.getText().toString());
int Last = Integer.parseInt(End.getText().toString());
for(int i=First; i<Last; i++) {
    result[i] = 1;
}
```

You are trying to call this code before the button is tapped and `result` is empty:

```
int i, num=0, num2=0;
for(i=0; i<=23; i++) {
    if(result[i] == 1) {
        num++;
    }
}
int[] Time = new int[num-1];
for(i=0; i<=23; i++) {
    if(result[i] == 1) {
        Time[num2]=i;
        num2++;
    }
}
```

Move that code inside you `onClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted the error log, I'm just guessing. In this code:

```
int i, num=0, num2=0;
for(i=0; i<=23; i++) {
    if(result[i] == 1) {
        num++;
    }
}
int[] Time = new int[num-1];
```

if there is not an element inside `result[]` equal to `1` then `num` will retain its initial value `0`.  
So after that you initialize `Time` as `int[-1]`.  
This would throw an exception like `java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException`

Answer (score 0):

After changing that code like this, the app is working! Thank you everyone.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
SingerAdapter adapter;
EditText Name;
EditText Start;
EditText End;

Button button;

//가능한 시간 값 0, 가능하지 않은 시간 값 1
int[] result = new int[24];

//버튼의 클릭 여부 확인 변수
int click=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Name = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Start = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    End = findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    adapter = new SingerAdapter();

    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String name = Name.getText().toString();
            String start = Start.getText().toString() + ":00";
            String end = End.getText().toString() + ":00";

            adapter.addItem(new SingerItem(name, start, end, R.drawable.human));

            //가능하지 않은 시간 체크
            int First = Integer.parseInt(Start.getText().toString());
            int Last = Integer.parseInt(End.getText().toString());
            for(int i=First; i<Last; i++) {
                result[i] = 1;
            }
        }

    });

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //아이템 클릭 리스너 설정
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            SingerItem item = (SingerItem) adapter.getItem(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "선택 : " + item.getName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //버튼이 클릭되었음을 표시
            click=1;
        }
    });

    if(click == 1) {
        //가능한 시간 Time[i]에 저장
        int num=0, num2=0;
        for(int i=0; i<=23; i++) {
            if(result[i] == 1) {
                num++;
            }
        }
        int[] Time = new int[num-1];
        for(int i=0; i<=23; i++) {
            if(result[i] == 1) {
                Time[num2]=i;
                num2++;
            }
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Arrays.toString(Time), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
public class SingerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<SingerItem> items = new ArrayList<SingerItem>();

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public void addItem(SingerItem item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        SingerItemView view = new SingerItemView(getApplicationContext());
        SingerItem item = items.get(position);
        view.setName(item.getName());
        view.setStart(item.getStart());
        view.setEnd(item.getEnd());
        view.setImage(item.getResId());

        return view;
    }
}
}
```